# Pie chart with multiple dummy variables

Tags: r, plot, new-operator, pie-chart

Lets suppose there are 4 persons and 3 groups (A, B, C) and 1 means it belongs to group X and 0 in other case. Lets suppose we have a database like this:

```
# A  B  C
1 0  0  1
2 0  1  0
3 1  0  0
4 1  0  0
```

What im trying to do is a pie chart that contains everygroup.

The code that im trying is

```
ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=data$A)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

However it only plots the pie chart of one variable.
Thank you

Comment: Please include the code you are trying and state what the problem or error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code performs the plot you want. I did some recoding using `pivot_longer` before making the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A,B,C),
               names_to = "group",
               values_to = "people") %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(Sumppl = sum(people)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y = Sumppl, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 1, position = "stack")+
  coord_polar("y") + 
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

[image: Pie plot]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to pivot the df first:

```
df  <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),  A = c(0, 0, 1, 1), B = c(0, 1, 0, 0), C = c(1, 0, 0, 0)) 

df  %>% 
      pivot_longer(2:4, names_to = "group", values_to = "value") %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x="", y=value, fill=group))+
      geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")+
      coord_polar("y", start=0)
```