# Pie plot of frequencies and pecentages of yes/no factors

Tags: r, data-visualization, pie-chart, dummy-variable, factors

I'm new to the R language, so please forgive me if my questions are a little basic. But I still couldn't come up with a solution.

I have a data frame with categorical variables that have yes/no levels. I'm attempting to use pie charts and histograms to represent the results of each level for all the variables (yes/no, coded as 0/1).

Let me show an example of my data.
I have 06 factors : A, B, C, D, E and G each factor has 0/1 levels.

```
set.seed(99)
A = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = T)
B = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = T)
C = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = T)
D = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = T)
E = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = T)
G = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = T)
df = data.frame(A,B,C,D,E,G)
df = as.data.frame(lapply(df, factor))
df %>%
pivot_longer(cols = c(A,B,C,D,E,G),
           names_to = "group",
           values_to = "people") %>%
group_by(group) %>%
summarize(Sumppl = length(people)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x="", y = Sumppl, fill = group)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 1, position = "stack")+
coord_polar("y") + 
 theme_minimal()+
 theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

I want to make a pie plot of all these variables for each level (0 and 1). Then I want compare each level for another categorical variable (sex with two modalities, Male/Female)

I tried this solution from another question : [Pie chart with multiple dummy variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102200/pie-chart-with-multiple-dummy-variables)
but it seems to give me a wrong answer, and I can figure out why (the length of vectors is the total number of all cases, not each level)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Without a sample of the data and what you mean by "gave me a wrong answer" we can't really help very much. Provide some rows of your data in using `dput()`. Also provide your code so far.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm sorry, hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but let's construct a simple table based on part of your code:

```
df = data.frame(A,B,C,D,E,G) # Note we are not converting to factors
df2 <- df %>%
pivot_longer(cols = c(A,B,C,D,E,G),
           names_to = "group",
           values_to = "people")
df2
#      people
# group  0  1
#     A 47 53
#     B 53 47
#     C 42 58
#     D 59 41
#     E 45 55
#     G 51 49
```

The rest of your code just sums the rows, but they all sum to 100 so your pie chart is not very informative. Is it your goal to produce a single pie chart using all of the data, or 6 pie charts representing each row of the data?